# Can't get the focus back into a txt box

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I've been working on this forever I feel like and can't find a solution.
The form has one 1 scannable field(txtbox) that 3 types of data get scanned into (BinLocation, SKU, NAS).  When a Binlocation is scanned the following SKU's/NAS's would all be logged into that binlocation.  When a new binlocation is scanned it updates and again, all SKU's and NAS's are now logged under that bin.  Binlocations always start with an R, SKUs always start with an S, and NASs always start with an O.  All this gets logged into a table.  The issue I'm having is once a binlocation is scanned, it won't focus back into that txtbox again.  I've tried having 3 txt boxes, but I get the same issue.  If I scan the bin, it locks that value and logs all SKUs and NASs under it, clearing and focusing back into the SKU and NAS field until I scan the next bin location.  It then logs the new bin, but completely skips the SKU field and sets focus into the NAS field.  Either way I haven't been able to figure this out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**(1 scannable field)**

```
Private Sub txtScan_LostFocus()
    Dim scanValue As String
    scanValue = Me.Txtscan.Value
    
    Static binLocation As String ' Variable to store the current bin location
    
    If Left(scanValue, 1) = "R" Then
        ' Bin Location scan
        binLocation = scanValue
    ElseIf Left(scanValue, 1) = "S" Then
        ' SKU scan
        If binLocation <> "" Then
            Me.Scanssubform.Form.Recordset.AddNew
            Me.Scanssubform.Form!binLocation = binLocation
            Me.Scanssubform.Form!SKU = scanValue
            Me.Scanssubform.Form.Update
        Else
            MsgBox "Please scan a bin location first.", vbExclamation, "Missing Bin Location"
        End If
    ElseIf Left(scanValue, 1) = "O" Then
        ' NAS scan
        If binLocation <> "" Then
            Me.Scanssubform.Form.Recordset.AddNew
            Me.Scanssubform.Form!binLocation = binLocation
            Me.Scanssubform.Form!NAS = scanValue
            Me.Scanssubform.Form.Update
        Else
            MsgBox "Please scan a bin location first.", vbExclamation, "Missing Bin Location"
        End If
    Else
        ' Invalid scan
        MsgBox "Invalid scan value.", vbExclamation, "Invalid Scan"
    End If
    
    ' Clear the scanned value
    Me.Txtscan.Value = ""
End Sub
```

**(3 scannable fields)**

```
Private previousControl As Control

Private Sub SKUTextbox_AfterUpdate()
    ' Check if the scanned SKU starts with "R"
    If Left(Me.SKUTextbox.Value, 1) = "R" Then
        Me.BinLocationTextbox.Value = Me.SKUTextbox.Value
        Me.SKUTextbox.Value = ""
        Me.NASTextbox.Value = ""
        Me.SKUTextbox.SetFocus
    Else
        Me.NASTextbox.SetFocus
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub NASTextbox_GotFocus()
    Set previousControl = Screen.ActiveControl
End Sub

Private Sub NASTextbox_AfterUpdate()
    If Left(Me.NASTextbox.Value, 1) = "R" Then
        Me.BinLocationTextbox.Value = Me.NASTextbox.Value
        Me.SKUTextbox.Value = ""
        Me.NASTextbox.Value = ""
        Me.SKUTextbox.SetFocus
    Else
        If Not previousControl Is Nothing Then
            previousControl.SetFocus
            Set previousControl = Nothing
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I've tried disabling controls so it doesn't focus into them.  Then it'll find something else to focus, like an export control or cleardata control.

Comment: Can't you just set the _tab order_ of these controls and skip the `SetFocus`?

Comment: Instead of using `LostFocus` could you use `KeyUp` and check for a Tab character?

Comment: What are tables and relationships? If SKU and NAS are related to a parent BIN, why are they scanned into same field/textbox?

Answer (score 0):

Hy Michael,

Here is what i did, created a txtScan;

[image]

The code i used is after update of the txtScan field.

```
Private Sub Txtscan_AfterUpdate()

If Me.Txtscan <> "" Then
    '
    'Function for writing to the table
    '
    Call CreateScanRecord(Me.Txtscan)
    '
    Me.txtStatus = "Scanned : " & Me.Txtscan
    
    'Clear scan
    Me.Txtscan = ""

    
End If
```

End Sub

The code for writing to the table :

```
Public Sub CreateScanRecord(ByVal strScanValue As String)

Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "Insert into tblTest (TestCD) Values ('" & strScanValue & "')"
'
Call CurrentDb.Execute(strSQL, dbSeeChanges)
```

End Sub

The thing is, i got the same result as you, the focus after the scan was going to the next control.

Example : Error : After adding a value in the txtScan and entering tab:
[image]

To solve this i set the txtStatus control tabstop to false.
Now i get this as a result :

[image]

You see that the focus is back on the txtscan.
To set the tabstop to false, go to control => properties => others => Tabstop : False.

I would also recommend using a function to write to the table instead of using your current way of adding data. It will seperate your concerns.

Good luck ...

Comment: Hy Michael, did this work out for you ?